# Two floating divs in div

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive-design

I have a `div` and two `div`s on one line in this master `div`. But I want, when I change the browser window, that the second `div` moves under the first `div`. I don't want horizontal scroll.

```css
div.footban {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

div.footban div {
  border: solid 1pt black;
  display: table;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footban">
  <div>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>
  <div>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `div.footban` :)

```css
div.footban {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.footban div {
  border: solid 1pt black;
  display: table;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="footban">
  <div>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>
  <div>Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jirin if my answer solved your problem please click the gray checkmark next to my answer to accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the @media queries

Just add the `display: block`

```
@media all and (max-width:768px){
    div.footban{display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.footban {
    display: flex;
}
```

when you set the display property of an element to `flex` like you did, the `flex-direction` by default is set to `row` which put every direct child element on the same line

when you resize you window you can just set some media query that take effect on certain size of your browser window and reset the `flex-direction` to `column` and that will put every direct child of the `div.footban` to be align verticaly and the second **div** will be under the first one

```
// I use 768px just for sample purpose

@media all and (min-width : 768px) {
    div.footban {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```